# JSON how to get squared brackets?

Tags: arrays, highcharts, json

I have the following code:

```
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(0).pair);
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(1).pair);
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(2).pair);
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(3).pair);
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(4).pair);
    array.put(allWaitClasses.get(0).allPairs.get(5).pair);
    json = array.toString();
```

What I get is the following:

```
[
    {
        "name": "User I/O"
    },
    {
        "key": "61410583140000"
    },
    ...
]
```

But what I want is squared brackets:

```
var data =[
    [
        1229904000000,
        12.74
    ],
    [
        1229990400000,
        115.20
    ],
    ...
```

Actually I want to follow the template of this API:
https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

So how can I get the squared brackets insteand of the curved ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should iterate over data and push items in following way :

```
      var arrayX = [];
       $.forEach( data, function ( item ) {
            arrayX .push( [
                    item.timestamp, item.value
            ] );
        } )
```

Comment: So it's better to this conversion on JS side instead of Java?

Comment: There should not be calculations/logis at Ui/JS end ideally . If you can get data in desired format its always good and improve performance but if you can't get data in desired format do it at JS end.